# How do I sniff HTTP traffic on OS X Lion?

Tags: networking, http

I'm developing a web application and I'm trying to check the HTTP traffic is going on whenever a page loads.

Which application can I use? I'm on OS X Lion. I'm fine with either command line based or gui based apps. I just need to know whenever the app does a GET/POST to the server.

Comment: why not good old tcpdump?

Comment: should add the command to specify http traffic: tcpdump -i <interface> port 80 or 443

Comment: Hi! Thanks to your comment. U reminded me of tcpdump and I went to do a search. I didn't know tcpdump could do that! Here is a link to the  [post](http://serverfault.com/questions/84750/monitoring-http-traffic-using-tcpdump) which gave me more details on what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark is the best tool for sniffing network traffic. And it works on Lion as this posting demonstrates: http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/5652/osx-lion-release